# Question about omnipotence of God

Tags: gods, philosophy

If God is omnipotent then

1. why can't parambrahm kill my soul(aatma)
2. Can parambrahm parmeshwar make a rock that can't be lifted by parambrahm?
3. Can God kill himself?

I don't want to offend anyone but I want to know answer of such contradictions

Edit:With these questions can I say God is omnipotent only to the subjects and aspects in maya. But not omnipotent in case of soul/aatma

Comment: God is not an individual and so these questions are irrelevant.

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay replace word God with almighth consciousness. Then?

Comment: Consciousness is not an individual. There is no way to define it. So the questions are irrelevant.

Comment: God cannot kill your soul because **aatma hi parmatma hai**, (Self is God).

Comment: Ocean does not seek rivers , because it *complete in
itself* satchitananda in its fullness, so It is the other way round .as in nature. In words of Gita  *nānavāptam avāptavyaṁ*(3.22), so, here the question is why should God kill a jivatma soul or himself ?for what? would arise .. So it is only your soul that can aspire for parambrahm being incomplete . An unattached creator is never bound by  creation, The One creator's universal energy prana causes insect, human to breathe,rivers to flow, stellar objects to move around.  what cant the creator lift as omnipotency is His own strength?

Comment: your question is non-nonsensical on many levels. Your soul (atman) is eternal. Your soul (atman) is omnipotent. Killing only occurs with the non-eternal. Rocks exist within the sensual universe. The sensual universe is unreal. There is no 'creation'. Creation is a western term. The vedas speak of 'sristhi' - projection. There is nothing to lift. Can you make the unreal Real? Can a mirage be made real?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from [Satyarth prakash chapter 7](http://satyarthprakash.in/english/chapter-seven/)

Is God All-powerful or not?

A.- Yes, He is, but what you understand by the word All- powerful is not right. It really means that God does not require the least assistance from any person in all His works such as Creation, Sustenance and Dissolution of the Universe, and administration of Divine Justice. In other words, He does all His works with His own infinite power.

. But we believe that God can do whatever He likes. There is no one above Him.

A.- What does He like? ***If you say that he likes and can do all things, we ask – “Can God kill Himself?” Or “can He make other Gods like Himself, become ignorant, commit sins such as theft, adultery and the like? Or can He be unhappy?” Your answer can only be in the negative, as these things are opposed to the nature and attributes of God; hence your contention, that God can do all things, does not hold good. Our meaning only, therefore, of the word All-powerful is true.***

> So, question like these are opposed to nature of very definition of
> God as defined in vedas

“That Supreme Being overspreads all. He is entirely spirit, All-energy, All-powerful, Pure, Perfect, Omniscient, Inward Controller of all, Ruler of All, Eternal and Self-existent. He has from all eternity been teaching uncreated immortal human souls, the true knowledge of things through the revelation of the Veda – His eternal knowledge.” YAJUR VEDA, :

Negative glorification consists in praising God as devoid of such ungodly qualities as passion and malice in the following way:- “He is never embodied, is never born, is never liable to division and is free from nervous or arterial systems, never commits a sin , is never subject to pain, grief and ignorance and the like.” YAJUR VEDA

Additionally, he is above human intellect
Bhagavad Gita: Chapter 3, Verse 42

> इन्द्रियाणि पराण्याहुरिन्द्रियेभ्य: परं मन: ।
>
> मनसस्तु परा बुद्धिर्यो बुद्धे: परतस्तु स: || 42||
>
> The senses are superior to the gross body, and superior to the senses
> is the mind. Beyond the mind is the intellect, and even beyond the
> intellect is the soul.

Answer (score 1):

The question assumes the omnipotence of God/Ishwara.

It is not clear if Ishwara is omnipotent. In some places, Ishwara admits that He cannot change some things.

**Bhagavad Gita**

> sadṛśaṅ cēṣṭatē svasyāḥ prakṛtērjñānavānapi.
> prakṛtiṅ yānti bhūtāni nigrahaḥ kiṅ kariṣyati৷৷3.33৷৷

> 3.33 Even a man of wisdom behaves according to his own nature. **Beings follow (their) nature. What can restraint do?**

While commenting on this sloka, Sri Adi Shankara says -

> tasmāt prakṛtiṅ yānti anugacchanti bhūtāni prāṇinaḥ. nigrahaḥ niṣēdharūpaḥ kiṅ kariṣyati mama vā anyasya vā৷৷

> Therefore, bhutani, beings; yanti, follow; (their) prakrtim, nature. Nigrahah kim karisyati, **what can restraint do, be it from Me (Krishna)** or anybody else?

Here, we find Bhagavan himself admitting that He cannot make people act contrary to their nature. This is an example that probably shows that Ishwara is not omnipotent. (But yes, there are other places where Ishwara is treated as omnipotent).