# Does the Brahman of Advaita Vedanta know every knowledge?

Tags: advaita, brahman, knowledge

The Advaitha vedanta  says that Brahman is the  *omnipresent*, *omniscient* and *omnipotent* being beyond any proper description that can be elaborated uses our 5 senses. Being the sat-chit-ananda can we say that Brahman possess all the secular and spiritual knowledge of the past present and future of the very existence.

Some questions are -
does Brahman know who will be the Nobel prize winner of the 30 th century, does Brahman know all the information about science , maths arts, literature etc as perceived by human beings , can Brahman go back in time to change certain things , can Brahman tell what is happening in any civilisation present in any planet in andromeda galaxy without the intervention of scientific tools of earth , just by his knowledge?

Comment: Premise of the Question itself is incorrect. The Attributes of Omniscience, Omnipotence have been held to be avidyakalpita by Adi Shankara in the brahmasutra bhasya. These qualities apply only to the sagunabrahman by the agency of maya, not to the nirgunabrahman of Advaita.

Comment: Very sorry , it completely escaped my mind , thank you for pointing it out. So does any scripture suggest that Sagunabrahman have all the attributes mentioned in the question , @user32843? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state of brahman is non-dual. There is no second entity in that state. There is no objective knowledge (knowledge of objects) in the state of brahman. **Therefore, technically, brahman does not know anything.**

**[Brihadaranyaka upanishad Verse 4.3.30](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brihadaranyaka-upanishad/d/doc120049.html)**

> yadvai tanna vijānāti vijānanvai tanna vijānāti, na hi vijñāturvijñāterviparilopo vidyate'vināśitvān; na tu taddvitīyamasti tato'nyadvibhaktaṃ yadvijānīyāt || 30 ||

> **That it does not know in that state is because, although knowing then, it does not know;** for the knower’s function of knowing can never be lost, because it is immortal. **But there is not that second thing separate from it which it can know.**

**Verse 4.3.31**

> yatra vā anyadiva syāt, tatrānyo'nyatpaśyet, anyo'nyajjighret, anyo'nyadrasayet, anyo'nyadvadet, anyo'nyacchṛṇuyāt, anyo'nyanmanvīta, anyo'nyatspṛśet, anyo'nyadvijānīyāt || 31 "||

> **When there is something else, as it were,** then one can see something, one can smell some-thing, one can taste something, one can speak something, one can hear something, one can think something, one can touch something, or **one can know something.**

**[Brihadaranyaka upanishad Verse 2.4.14](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brihadaranyaka-upanishad/d/doc117950.html)**

> yatra hi dvaitamiva bhavati taditara itaraṃ jighrati, taditara itaraṃ paśyati, taditara itaram śrṇoti, taditara itaramabhivadati, taditara itaram manute, taditara itaraṃ vijānāti; yatra vā asya sarvamātmāivābhūttatkena kaṃ jighret, tatkena kaṃ paśyet, tatkena kaṃ śṛṇuyat, tatkena kamabhivadet, tatkena kaṃ manvīta, tatkena kaṃ vijānīyāt? yenedam sarvaṃ vijānāti, taṃ kena vijānīyāt? vijñātāram are kena vijānīyāditi || 14 ||

> **Because when there is duality, as it were**, then one smells something, one sees something, one hears something, one speaks something, one thinks something, **one knows something.**...**(But) when to the knower of Brahman everything has become the Self,** then what should one smell and through what, what should one see and through what, what should one hear and through what, what should one speak and through what, what should one think and through what, **what should one know and through what?** Through what should one know That owing to which all this is known—through what, O Maitreyī, should one know the Knower ?

Comment: Then why does anyone want to realise such non dual Brahman , rather than any dual-god?

Comment: @SoumyadipDas according to the upanishads, one is already brahman, whether one realizes it or not. Realization will liberate one from birth-death cycle and as brahman is bliss, realization removes suffering.

Comment: I have no argument against that, but what I want to know is that , whether the Brahman with attributes knows everything and has the power to manifest and change every thing, if it wills. Thank you @estimator.

Comment: @SoumyadipDas Yes, brahman with attributes knows everything. Whether brahman has all powers is not clear. Please check this - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58193/31356